# Looking for help in using names for a business

Tags: differences

My brother and I are starting a business and would like to use our names for the business.  For example Kate & Larry's restaurant.  Or is it Kate's & Larry's Restaurant.  Thanks

Comment: Compare "Ivanka and Jared's security clearance".

Comment: Never heard of Ivanka and Jared. Certainly you have heard of Ben and Jerry, though.

Answer (score 0):

As you and your brother will jointly own the business, the correct naming is:
'Kate and Larry's Restaurant'.

Where two or more people own one item jointly, place an apostrophe before an "s" only after the second-named person. For example:

Incorrect: Bill's and Mary's car was slow
Correct: Bill and Mary's car was slow

However, when two or more people own two or more items separately, each individual's name should take the possessive form. For example:

Incorrect: Joanne and Todd's cars were bought from the same dealer.
Correct: Joanne's and Todd's cars were bought from the same dealer.